# How can I make an HTTP request that checks if a DB entry exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application connected to a PostgreSQL database.

This server will be receiving HTTP requests such as `POST` from another software to store some statistics, but I want to avoid having to undergo the process of acquiring all of those statistics again if an entry that matches some of the identifiers that the statistics has already exists in the database.

How can I do this check from the software-side, instead of server-side?

That is, without an usual `GET` method, because that will possibly return a very large list, to the point where it becomes too expensive to find a matching entry and to make this check in the application.

Comment: what is " software-side"?  Why not just return the calculation results from the POST request to the caller?  Anyways, your question is unclear and requires more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly!

There are several options to launch some functionality without waiting for external requests.
One option is to use the @Scheduled functionality of spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    daoSevice.execute();
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Good luck!